# Images display in black - CSS

Tags: css, image, button

I have an image that sometimes displays normally, but others times it just shows up black:

The HTML:

```
 <button class="myImage">
    <?php echo _('My image') ?>
 </button>
```

The CSS:

```
.myImage { 
    background: url("../img/myImage.png") no-repeat;
}
```

I think the trouble comes from the background assigned to a button tag. But I cant change the button tag so how can I circumvent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set a default background to all the buttons you use, so if the image ever fails, it won't flash black?

```
button { background: transparent; } /* Or some solid color that's not black */
```

Comment: Ok , it could be an answer : do you think it could force to display if I specifiy the style directly inside the button tag ?

Comment: If you want to force it, use: background-color: transparent !important; That way you don't have to manually insert it inline for each button, and you can add the background image without issues/conflicts on the color.